# pocketsphinx: return long utterance as single result

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

When analyzing a sound file approximately 1 minute long, pocketsphinx breaks the file into multiple results. Is there a way to change the code to return a single utterance? I'm using code based on `continuous_test.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import environ, path

from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "../../../model"
DATADIR = "../../../test/data"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)

stream = open(path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'rb')
#stream = open('10001-90210-01803.wav', 'rb')

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

Comment: You might be able to set a long value for `secondsOfSilenceToDetect`

Answer (score -1):

```
result = "" 

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                result = result + decoder.hyp().hypstr
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()

return result
```

Comment: This just concatenates each result. You still get all of the <s> tags, for instance.

Comment: result.replace('<s>', '')

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't let me see overall confidence scores, etc. Why and how does it break up the utterance, rather than returning one result?